# Regex pattern without one case

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I would like to remove some strings from filename.
I want to remove every string in bracket but not if there is a string "remix" or "Remix" or "REMIX"
Now I have got

`sed "s/\s*\(\s?[A-z0-9. ]*\)//g"`

but how to exclude cases when there is remix in string?

Comment: for all variant cases of 'remix' -> python  st.upper() == 'REMIX'

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: I think it is easier with perl: `perl -pe 's|\s*\((?i:(?!remix)[^()])*\)||g'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a capture group:

```
sed 's/\(\s*([^)]*remix[^)]*)\)\|\s*(\s\?[a-z0-9. ]*)/\1/gi'
```

When the "remix branch" doesn't match, the capture group is not defined and the matched part is replaced with an empty string.

When the "remix branch" succeeds, the matched part is replaced by the content of the capture group, so by itself.

Note: if that helps to avoid false positive, you can add word-boundaries around "remix": `\bremix\b`

pattern details:

```
\(           # open the capture group 1
    \s*      # zero or more white-spaces
    (        # a literal parenthesis
    [^)]*    # zero or more characters that are not a closing parenthesis
    remix
    [^)]*
    )   
\)           # close the capture group 1
\|           # OR
# something else between parenthesis

\s*  # note that it is essential that the two branches are able to
     # start at the same position. If you remove \s* in the first
     # branch, the second branch will always win when there's a space
     # before the opening parenthesis.
(\s\?[a-z0-9. ]*)
```

`\1` is the reference to the capture group 1

`i` makes the pattern case-insensitive

[EDIT]

If you want to do it in a POSIX compliant way, you must use a different approach because several Gnu features are not available, in particular the alternation `\|` (but also the `i` modifier, the `\s` character class, the optional quantifier `\?`).

This other approach consists to find *all eventual characters that are not an opening parenthesis and all eventual substrings enclosed between parenthesis with "remix" inside, followed by eventual white-spaces and an eventual substring enclosed between parenthesis*.

As you can see all is optional and the pattern can match an empty string, but it isn't a problem.

All before the parenthesis part to remove is captured in group 1.

```
sed 's/\(\([^(]*([^)]*[Rr][Ee][Mm][Ii][Xx][^)]*)[^ \t(]*\([ \t]\{1,\}[^ \t(]\{1,\}\)*\)*\)\([ \t]*([^)]*)\)\{0,1\}/\1/g;'
```

pattern details:

```
\(     # open the capture group 1
    \(
        [^(]*  # all that is not an opening parenthesis
        # substring enclosed between parenthesis without "remix"
        ( [^)]* [Rr][Ee][Mm][Ii][Xx] [^)]* )

        # Let's reach the next parenthesis without to match the white-spaces
        # before it (otherwise the leading white-spaces are not removed)
        [^ \t(]*  # all that is not a white-space or an opening parenthesis
        # eventual groups of white-spaces followed by characters that are
        # not white-spaces nor opening parenthesis
        \( [ \t]\{1,\} [^ \t(]\{1,\} \)*
    \)*
\)     # close the capture group 1
\(
    [ \t]*  # leading white-spaces
    ([^)]*) # parenthesis
\)\{0,1\}   # makes this part optional (this avoid to remove a "remix" part
            # alone at the end of the string)
```

The word boundaries in this mode aren't available too. So the only way to emulate them is to list the four possibilities:

```
([Rr][Ee][Mm][Ii][Xx])                # poss1
([Rr][Ee][Mm][Ii][Xx][^a-zA-Z][^)]*)  # poss2
([^)]*[^a-zA-Z][Rr][Ee][Mm][Ii][Xx])  # poss3
([^)]*[^a-zA-Z][Rr][Ee][Mm][Ii][Xx][^a-zA-Z][^)]*) # poss4
```

and to replace `([^)]*[Rr][Ee][Mm][Ii][Xx][^)]*)` with:

```
\(poss1\)\{0,\}\(poss2\)\{0,\}\(poss3\)\{0,\}\(poss4\)\{0,\}
```

Comment: Please note that this method relies on `i` flag, which is available in GNU sed, but not POSIX sed. If the intention is to write portable code, then `remix` needs to be rewritten as `[Rr][Ee][Mm][Ii][Xx]`

Comment: @nhahtdh: I added a POSIX compliant way.

Answer (score 1):

Just skip the lines matching "remix":

```bash
sed '/([^)]*[Rr][Ee][Mm][Ii][Xx][^)]*)/! s/([^)]*)//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

where bracket are (US) :`[]`

```
sed '/remix\|REMIX\|Remix/ !s/\[[^]]*]//g'
```

where bracet (ROW): `()`

```
sed '/remix\|REMIX\|Remix/ !s/([^)]*)//g'
```

assuming:
 - there is no internal bracket
 - Other form of remix are excluced (`ReMix`, ...), so line is deleted
 - Remix could be any place in title (`i love remix`) [if needed specify which to take and remove]

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but what are you doing in the `s///` command? The OP knows what he wants there.

Comment: @glennjackman  thanks for editing and make the code error free or with useless group. for the `s///` *I want to remove every string in bracket* so i delete the internal content